# Injetar o Dao no Converter

Tags: jsf, cdi

Estou tendo um erro de java.lang.NullPointerException em um Conversor no momento em que ele vai acessar o banco, pelo visto o a dependência não esta sendo injetada pelo CDI, existe argumentos de que o Conversor não deve acessar o Banco mais no meu caso eu não estou conseguindo fazer a view com um Dialogo do Primefaces funcionar, sem o Dialogo ela funciona, com ele não então por isto o Converter alterado, mais como fazer funcionar?

Projeto com JSF 2.2 + CDI + JPA, em Tomcat 8 Java 8
já vi Converter com a injeção do Dao só que eu não estou tendo sucesso o erro é 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.dominio.conversor.EstadoConverter.getAsObject(EstadoConverter.java:29)
não sei se em projetos em que vi este tipo de converter tenha.... digamos os dados ( o EntityManager em sessão ) vai ver que a instancia esta sendo criada mais o EntityManager seja o problema?

Segue o MB

```
@Named(value = "municipioC")
@ViewScoped
public class MunicipioController extends AbstractMB {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int totalRegistros;
    private List<Municipio> elementos;
    private List<Estado> estados;
    private Municipio registroSelecionado;
    private Municipio municipio;

    @Inject
    private MunicipioService municipioService;

    @Inject
    private EstadoService estadoService;

    public MunicipioController() {
    }
}
```

Segue o Converter

```
FacesConverter(forClass = Estado.class)
public class EstadoConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    EstadoDao dao ;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {

    System.out.println("EstadoConverter - getAsObject - valor: "+value);        

    Estado estado = null;

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)){
        Integer Id = Integer.parseInt(value);
        // Na linha Abaixo ocorre o erro 
        estado = this.dao.findByID(Id);
    }

    return estado;
}
```

e a view

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/Layout.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <h1 class="aw-page-title">Municípios</h1>

    <h:form id="frm">

        <p:toolbar>
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:commandButton id="btnAdd" title="Novo registro"
                    action="#{municipioC.preparaInclusao}"
                    oncomplete="PF('itemDialog').show()" process="@this"
                    update=":itemForm:itemPanel" icon="fa fa-fw fa-plus" />

                <p:commandButton id="btnEdi" title="Edita registro"
                    action="#{municipioC.preparaAlteracao}"
                    oncomplete="PF('itemDialog').show()" process="@this"
                    update=":itemForm:itemPanel" icon="fa fa-fw fa-edit" />

            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:messages autoUpdate="false" />
        <p:dataTable id="itensTable" widgetVar="dataTable" var="item"
            loadingMessage="Carregando..." emptyMessage="Nenhum registro."
            reflow="true" value="#{municipioC.elementos}" selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{municipioC.registroSelecionado}"
            rowKey="#{item.id}" style="margin-top:10px">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{municipioC.selectRegistro}" />

            <p:column headerText="Id" style="width:50px">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Municipio">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.dsMunicipio}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Uf">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.estado.siglaEstado}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="itemDialog" id="iditemDialog" header="Gerencia municipios"
        responsive="true" resizable="false" showEffect="explode"
        hideEffect="bounce" style="min-width: 400px" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">

        <h:form id="itemForm">

            <h:panelGroup id="itemPanel" layout="block" styleClass="ui-fluid"
                style="margin-top:10px;">
                <p:messages id="msgDialog" autoUpdate="false" />

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid"
                    styleClass="panelgrid-noborder"
                    columnClasses="ui-grid-col-4, ui-grid-col-8">

                    <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Municipio:" />
                    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{municipioC.municipio.dsMunicipio}"
                        placeholder="Municipio" size="50" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="ibge" value="Codigo IBGE:" />
                    <p:inputText id="ibge" value="#{municipioC.municipio.codIbge}"
                        placeholder="Codigo IBGE" size="10" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="estado" value="Estado" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="estado"
                        value="#{municipioC.municipio.estado}" required="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{municipioC.estados}" var="itemE"
                            itemValue="#{itemE}" itemLabel="#{itemE.dsEstado}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                </p:panelGrid>

            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-fw fa-save" title="Salvar"
                        action="#{municipioC.salvar}" process="itemPanel"
                        update="itemPanel"
                        oncomplete="closeDialogIfSucess(xhr, status, args, PF('itemDialog'), 'itemDialog')" />

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente o `@Inject` não funciona com a anotação `@FacesConverter`.

Existem outras formas de resolver essa problema. Uma delas é substituir a anotação:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Estado.class)
```

por

```
@Named
```

e usar

```
<p:selectOneMenu converter="#{estadoConverter}" />
```

Outra forma seria utilizar a bilbioteca [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/), que desde a versão 1.6 possui suporte a `@Inject` em um `@FacesConverter`.

---

Para mais detalhes, veja essa [resposta completa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7531487/1478419) do @BalusC.

Comment: Marcelo obrigado pela interação, usei o OmniFaces e continuou o problema então entendo que a injeção poderia até estar sendo feita o lance então seria o EntityManager ou seja ao acessar o banco e fazer a consulta. Alterei então minha classe Estado.java comentei  //bi-directional many-to-one association to Municipio
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy="estado")
    //private List<Municipio> municipios e em Municipio.java retirei o //@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) ficando só @ManyToOne e esta tudo ok, poderias comentar? com Spring eu usava o openEntityManagerInViewFilter agora tenho só CDI

Comment: Apenas um detalhe sobre o OmniFaces: a página da [documentação](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter) comenta sobre anotar o `beans.xml` para `bean-discovery-mode="all"`. Geralmente o utilizado é `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`. Realmente tem que fazer a mudança para que funcione.